# C++ Data Structure for storing 3 dimensions of floats

Tags: c++, 3d, data-structures

I've implemented a 3D strange attractor explorer which gives float XYZ outputs in the range 0-100, I now want to implement a colouring function for it based upon the displacement between two successive outputs.

I'm not sure of the data structure to use to store the colour values for each point, using a 3D array I'm limited to rounding to the nearest int which gives a very coarse colour scheme.

I'm vaguely aware of octtrees, are they suitable in this siutation?

EDIT: A little more explanation:

to generate the points i'm repeatedly running this:

(a,b,c,d are random floats in the range -3 to 3)

```
x = x2;
y = y2;
z = z2;

x2 = sin(a * y) - z * cos(b * x);
y2 = z2 * sin(c * x) - cos(d * y);
z2 = sin(x);

parr[i][0]=x;
parr[i][1]=y;
parr[i][2]=z;
```

which generates new positions for each axis each run, to colour the render I need to take the distance between two successive results, if I just do this with a distance calculation between each run then the colours fade back and forth in equilibrium so I need to take running average for each point and store it, using a 3dimenrsionl array is too coarse a colouring and I'm looking for advice on how to store the values at much smaller increments.

Comment: what is a "strange attractor explorer" ?

Comment: Is a 3 float struct what you want or...?

Comment: Something like: http://www.chaoscope.org/

But in my case a free camera is used to travel around and within the point cloud.

Comment: The values for the colouring are cumulative so I need to be able to access positions in the data storange structure to +/- 0.001 accuracy in all dimensions, for incrementing and reading out to render.

Comment: can you outline how you've implemented the 'strange attractor explorer'?

Comment: ok, i've added it to the question.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by having the colours 'fade back and forth in equilibrium'. Is it because you are mapping several points to a single pixel, and the last point written to screen overwrites the previous ones? Also, how are you rendering your points.. are they raytraced or rasterized?

Comment: Looking at the output you're very right, it's rasterized and it's drawing new points to old pixels. Thanks.

Comment: ah. so your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, the scintillation has far reduced now I've implemented a simple distance ordered render so that seems to be the problem.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably think bout some kind of 3-d binary search tree.

```
template <class KEY, class VALUE>
class BinaryTree
{
    // some implementation, probably available in libraries
public:
    VALUE* Find(const KEY& key) const
    {
        // real implementation is needed here
        return NULL; 
    }

};

// this tree nodes wil actually hold color
class BinaryTree1 : public BinaryTree<double, int>
{
};

class BinaryTree2 : public BinaryTree<double, BinaryTree1>
{
};

class BinaryTree3 : public BinaryTree<double, BinaryTree2>
{
};
```

And you function to retreive the color from this tree would look like that

```
bool    GetColor(const BinaryTree3& tree, double dX, double dY, double& dZ, int& color)
{
    BinaryTree2* pYTree = tree.Find(dX);
    if( NULL == pYTree )
        return false;

    BinaryTree1* pZTree = pYTree->Find(dY);
    if( NULL == pZTree )
        return false;

    int* pCol = pZTree->Find(dZ);
    if( NULL == pCol )
        return false;

    color = *pCol;
    return true;
}
```

Af course you will need to write the function that would add color to this tree, provided 3 coordinates X, Y and Z.
std::map appears to be a good candidate for base class.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could drop the 2-dim array off and use an 1-dim array of

```
struct ColoredPoint {

   int   x;
   int   y;
   int   z;

   float color;
};
```

so that the code would look like

```
 ...
 parr[i].x     = x;
 parr[i].y     = y;
 parr[i].z     = z;
 parr[i].color = some_computed_color;
```

(you may also wish to encapsulate the fields and use `class ColoredPoint` with access methods)

Comment: And given (x,y,z) how will you find color? Linear search?

Comment: From the initial post 

"...I now want to implement a colouring function for it based upon the displacement between two successive outputs..."

it's not clear if the access to the color value by (x,y,z) is required at all.

Comment: access for rendering based on depth into the screen is required so I'm going for the 3-d binary search tree rather than an array of structs.

Comment: "..access for rendering based on depth into the screen is required"

Thanks for the clarification. Using 3 trees seems excessive to me in terms both performance and space. You will have to perform a few dereference operations (costly for modern CPUs unless accessed memory is in the L1/L2 cache) and undertake the space overhead of 2 (unnecessary) trees.

Given that (x,y,z) is search key, you may simply use 1 tree and lexicograpical order on triples 

(node1.x,node1.y,node1.z) <= (node2.x,node2.y,node3.z)

to sort/rebalance/search in the tree

Comment: actually, space overhead depends on your data (whether they are sparse or not)